Existe-t-il un mot pour les « animaux non humains » ?
Puisque les humains sont des animaux, existe-t-il un mot pour désigner les animaux non humains ?
Cette question répond à ma question pour la langue anglaise.
Il est proposé le terme "wildlife" qui est en effet la bonne réponse pour l'anglais britannique.

Wildlife (UK) Animals that live independently of people, in natural conditions

À noter que c'est incorrect pour l'anglais américain puisque :

[Wildlife (USA)] Animals and plants that grow independently of people, usually in natural conditions

À noter que les animaux domestiques ne sont pas inclus dans les animaux non humains ce qui est assez surprenant !
Puisque la traduction littérale de "wildlife" est « la vie sauvage » et que, celle-ci, en français prend le sens d'animaux et de plantes, cette traduction ne répond pas à la question !
La deuxième réponse apportée dans EEL.se est « bête », est-ce pour vous la bonne réponse ?

Bête correspondrait en effet bien à la définition d' "animal non humain", selon le CNRTL ou le Larousse. Pour faire un rapide parallèle à la littérature, on peut penser à Emile ZOLA avec son roman La bête humaine, dont le titre en oxymore reflète l'inhumanité de certains caractères ou personnages pourtant humains (dans le sens homo sapiens).
Sinon, j'aurais employé animal sauvage (wild animal en anglais).

Je plussoie (faute d'avoir une meilleure suggestion) mais « bête » a, à mes oreilles, une connotation de danger. Je n’employerais pas le terme pour un animal approvisé correctement dressé, ni pour un animal sauvage de petite taille (par exemple un papillon).

C'est vrai, je suis d'accord. Je pense également au terme "bestiole", qui rapporterait généralement à un organisme étranger qui suscite la curiosité ou le dégoût, mais qui fait surtout planer un mystère autour de la nature de l'être vivant.
